# I have trouble with trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have to table with row below:

- Table `OrderDetail`: `idorder`, `productId`, `quantity`, `price`, `total`
- Table `Product`: `productId`, `productname`,..., `soldQuantity`

My trigger on `OrderDetail` table:

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[Sold]
On [dbo].[OrderDetail]
FOR Insert
AS
UPDATE Product
SET soldQuantity = soldQuantity + inserted.quantity
FROM Product inner join inserted
ON Product.productId  = inserted.productId
```

When i insert to `OrderDetail` table, nothing add to soldQuantity in `Product` table...

Comment: Is soldQuantity NULL? If so, it will remain NULL with this code because NULL + anything will equal NULL. You would need to use coalesce or isnull to solve that.

Comment: Ideally, don't *store* data that can be calculated. By storing the data, you *introduce* the opportunity for it to be stale/out of date, and now you're having to manually write triggers and get those right. If you *have* to store calculable data, ideally use a mechanism (such as an `indexed view`, here) where *SQL Server* takes care of maintaining the aggregates. BTW, your trigger is broken anyway. If there are multiple rows in `inserted` for a single product, it may only apply the `quantity` adjustment for *one* of those rows and ignore the others.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever , you are right

Comment: How i can apply for multi row?

Answer (score 0):

try using an alias:

```
UPDATE P
SET P.soldQuantity = P.soldQuantity + inserted.quantity
FROM Product P 
inner join inserted
   ON P.productId  = inserted.productId
```